# Android: Rotating large image crashes without throwing an error

Tags: android, image, crash, rotation

I have searched and found simple code to rotate an image. I am pulling the image out of an ImageView object into a bitmap, rotating it then putting it back. I realize this is not the most effective method but I don't think it should crash without giving an error message in the CATCH block.

Here is my code. The only value passed in is "r" or "l" depending on which direction I want to rotate. Smaler images (1500x1500 or smaller) work just fine. Things go bad around the 2500x2500 size.

```
public void rotate(String dir)
{
    try
    {
        float angle = (dir.equals("r") ? 90 : -90);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Utilities.logError(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Any clue as to why it is crashing and why it doesn't thow an exception? I just get a message "Unfortuantly process .... has stopped" and I get kicked back to the welcome screen of my app.

Oh, for kicks I set the angle to ZERO (hard coded) and it didn't crash. I suspect that it is just taking too long to rotate and Android is having a fit. But I am not sure how to confirm that as the problem or how to tell Android to wait a little longer.

Even if I reduce the preview image for the rotation, when I go to save I will have to rotate the full size image at least once and will hit this same issue. Won't I?

Comment: its a crash post the stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can more or less guarantee without looking at the logs that you're getting an Out Of Memory Exception.

You need to use smaller images, or use a different method to rotate that doesn't use up so much memory (you're allocating 2 2500x2500 bitmaps at the same time here! that's tons!).

Try using a RotateAnimation to get your effect instead.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It was partly memory and partly a timeout issue. I was rotating in the UI thread and it was taking just a little too long in some cases. It only ran out of memory when my app was doing some other stuff too but I bet it would have been a problem on many other devices. So much for emulators. None of them had an issue. Only the real phone. THANKS!